# Prove that $ G $ has a Sylow $ 2 $-subgroup

Tags: finite-groups, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I am reading Finite Group Theory by Martin Isaacs section 2C ([see here](https://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA45&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and I currently stuck on one minor detail in his proof of theorem 2.15:

> Suppose for every odd prime $ p $, every $ p $-local subgroup of a finite group $ G $ has a normal Sylow $ 2 $-subgroup. Then $ G $ has a normal Sylow $ 2 $-subgroup. A subgroup is $ p $-local if it is the normalizer of a nontrivial $ p $-subgroup.

### Isaacs' proof:

First suppose $ O_{2}(G) = 1 $ where $ O_{2}(G) $ is the intersection of all Sylow $ 2 $-subgroups of $ G $. We will show $ |G| $ is odd (this implies $ G $ has a normal Sylow $ 2 $-subgroup, namely the trivial group). If $ |G| $ has even order, then there exists an involution $ t $ and $ t \notin O_{2}(G) $. We then know that there exists an $ x $ with odd order prime $ p $ such that $ x^t = x^{-1} $. Let $ X = \left< x \right> $. Then $ t \in \text{N}_{G}(X) $ and $ \text{N}_{G}(X) $ is local. **By the hypothesis $ \text{N}_{G}(X) $ has a normal Sylow $ 2 $-subgroup $ S $ and $ t \in S $.** Since $ X $ and $ S $ are normal in $ \text{N}_{G}(X) $ and $ X \cap S = 1 $, they commute. So $ x = x^t = x^{-1} $, so $ x $ has order $ 2 $, a contradiction. Hence $ |G| $ has odd order. Now if $ O_{2}(G) > 1 $ then he basically looked at the factor group $ G / O_{2}(G) $ and reduce to the first case again.

---

I understand the proof but in the bold sentence he claimed that $ \text{N}_{G}(X) $ has a normal Sylow $ 2 $-subgroup $ S $ and $ t \in S $. Why must $ S $ contain $ t $?

Comment: Do you see why $t\in N_G(X)$ (as stated just before the bolded part)? From that it follows because $t$ has order $2$ and the normal Sylow $2$-subgroup contains all elements of order a power of $2$.